# Custom ValidationAttribute test against whole model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, validationattribute

I know this is probably not possible but let's say I have a model with two properties.

I write a ValidationAttribute for one of the properties.  Can that VA look at the other property and make a decision?

So;

```
public class QuickQuote
{
    public String state { get; set; }

    [MyRequiredValidator(ErrorMessage = "Error msg")]
    public String familyType { get; set; }
```

So in the above example, can the validator test to see what's in the "state" property and take that into consideration when validating "familyType"?

I know I can probably save the object to the session but would like to avoid any saving of state if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve this kind of validation is to have your model implement IDataErrorInfo. That way you can do whole viewmodel validation.

[This page](http://www.asp.net/Learn/mvc/tutorial-37-cs.aspx) has some information about iplementing the IDataErrorInfo Interface, about 2/3 of the way down under the heading "mplementing the IDataErrorInfo Interface"

Comment: +1, this may be what I'm looking for.  Reading it now thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your custom validation could be applied to the class directly, take a look at PropertiesMustMatch attribute in the AccountModels class that is created by default as a part of the MVC project template in VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Use ValidationContext to get your model:

```
 public class MyRequiredValidator: RequiredAttribute
    {
        public override bool RequiresValidationContext
        {
            get {return true;} //it needs another propertie in model            
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            QuickQuote model = (QuickQuote)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

            if (model.state == "single")
                return null;
            else
                return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);//familyType is require for married
        }      
    }
```