# Custom Validation Attribute using Reflection?

Tags: c#, validation, attributes, annotations

I want to use the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly to validate arguments (mapped to properties) for a console app I'm working on.  I'll be using the "buddy class" metadata pattern; it's worked well for me in the past.

One of the things I need to validate is that exactly one of two types of arguments are provided.  In other words, argument `foo` can be specified, or argument `bar`, but not both, and not neither.

To this end I started writing a custom validation attribute, which seemed fairly straightforward, but I got a bit lost when I realized I needed to reach outside the property of the validation context, and traverse to a sibling property in the object I am validating (like the `CompareAttribute`).  It seems this is a classic reflection case, but I am scratching my head as to how to proceed.  This is what I have so far:

```
/// <summary>
/// This property, or the other specified, are required, but both cannot be set.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class XORAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// If validation should fail, return this error message.
    /// </summary>
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the other required property that is mutually exclusive of this one.
    /// </summary>
    public string OtherValueName { get; set; }

    public XORAttribute(string otherValueName)
    {
        this.OtherValueName = otherValueName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //Something needs to go here.
    }
}
```

Some assistance here would be appreciated.

Comment: Really?  No takers?  I would have assumed this was an easy question for ppl experienced in validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examining other properties with an attribute isn't all that easy.  [Other people on here have asked the same question (as seen in this link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783865/class-model-level-validation-as-opposed-to-property-level-asp-net-mvc-2-0/2784319#2784319) and the answer's, well, not super pretty.  [Another answer on here recommends using IDataErrorInfo to perform full class validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649581/custom-validationattribute-test-against-whole-model).

Comment: Not the answer I would have liked, but it seems like the right one.